# Cannot get data from React Native asynchronous file reading into Function Component (but works in Class Component)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have this working in a React Native Class Component, but cannot get it to work in a Function Component. I am reading data from a text file using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). The file is read asynchronously and the data is available as a javascript Promise object. First the working code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/Quote1.txt`;

RNFS.writeFile(path, 'The price of freedom is eternal vigilance.', 'utf8')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  });

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { myResourceContent: 'not loaded yet' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8').then((content) => {
      this.setState({ myResourceContent: content });
      console.log(`FILE READ: ${content}`);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { myResourceContent } = this.state;
    return (
      <Text>{myResourceContent}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to load the text file and to render it on the screen. But when trying to do the same thing in a in a Function Component, I can read the data from the file (as seen in the log), but I cannot get it out of the Promise object to render the text on the screen. I have read many async-await related answers here and also tried to use React Hooks, but I seem to be missing something foundational. Here is the code I tried:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/Quote1.txt`;

RNFS.writeFile(path, 'The price of freedom is eternal vigilance.', 'utf8')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  });

const mycontent  = RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8').then((content) => {
    return content;
  });

async function getMyContent() {
  const aw = await mycontent;
  console.log(`FILE READ: ${aw}`);
  return aw;
};

getMyContent();

export default function App() {
  const myResourceContent  = getMyContent();
  console.log(`QUOTE: ${myResourceContent}`);
  return (
    <Text>'QUOTE: '</Text>
  );
}
```

The `async function getMyContent` correctly receives the file data, but then I cannot get the text data into the `export default function App`. This was very easy to do in the class based code above, but here I get a promise object which does not seem to contain the text outside of the async function. The log shows:

```
LOG      QUOTE: [object Object]
LOG      FILE WRITTEN!
LOG      FILE READ: The price of freedom is eternal vigilance.
```

Using another approach, when I tried to declare a state variable and attempted to `useState` inside the async function I receive the error: "*Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): Error: Invalid hook call.*" I understand that I probably need to integrate the useState hook to replicate the class component features:

```
  const [myResourceContent, setContent] = useState(0);
  setContent(content);
```

If this is actually the correct approach, where am I supposed to place this (and any missing) code? If this is not the correct approach what would be the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I had to write your class that works as a functional component I would do this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const RNFS = require("react-native-fs");
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/Quote1.txt`;

RNFS.writeFile(path, "The price of freedom is eternal vigilance.", "utf8").then(
    () => {
        console.log("FILE WRITTEN!");
    }
);

const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ myResourceContent: "not loaded yet" });

    useEffect(() => {
        RNFS.readFile(path, "utf8").then((content) => {
            setState({ myResourceContent: content });
            console.log(`FILE READ: ${content}`);
        });
    }, []);

    return <Text>{state.myResourceContent}</Text>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: see the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) for the use of the second argument of useEffect . "While passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount mental model"

Comment: There is a difference in timing between the implementations: "Timing of effects: Unlike componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, the function passed to useEffect fires after layout and paint, during a deferred event. ... Although useEffect is deferred until after the browser has painted, it’s guaranteed to fire before any new renders. React will always flush a previous render’s effects before starting a new update." (_React doc_)

--- What effect does this have in **React Native**? Will the "not loaded yet" (as initial state) usually be displayed before showing the actual file content?

Comment: I'm not sure I would say yes because what you pass in useEffect is asynchronous but the best would be to use a useState loading in boolean that you change once it is finished

Comment: So I tested it on iOS and Android and the "not loaded yet" is actually displayed on the simulator for about 30 ms on iOS (not visible) and about 150 ms on Android (visible). The timing can be seen in the log file when adding an additional console.log statement. (obviously I do not need to show the message)

Answer (score 2):

You can have state in function components using hooks:

```
export default function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getMyContent().then(result => setContent(result));
  });
  return (
    <Text>{content}</Text>
  );
}
```

Once the content is loaded, the state will be set and the component will re-render with the text.

If you want to use a placeholder while the content is loading, you can set the initial value in useState:

```
const [content, setContent] = useState("Loading text");
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Thanks for your very helpful solution. I am starting to understand useEffect better now.